# \tcolorbox destroys page layout when put in header

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox

I want to add a coloured box in header, but when I do so it destroys completely my page layout and footer are just appearing anywhere. Note also how I have brutally aligned right and left header ... and that I have to add some space in order to see anything.

I'm very thankful for your help.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{longtitle/.style={%
  title={#1},
  before upper={\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\phantom{#1}\\[\the\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox]},
  after upper={\end{tabular}}}}

\newtcbox{\LongTitleBox}[1][]{longtitle={\Large \textbf{Test Header}},colbacktitle=black,coltitle=white,#1,colback=gray!20,boxrule=1pt}%

\newtcbox{\LongTitleBoxResult}[1][]{enhanced,longtitle={Final Result},colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black, #1}%

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{%
\fancyhead[L]{\LARGE \LongTitleBox{Test Title}}
\fancyhead[R]{Autor Name\\[0.5cm]}%
}



\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\wd0+12pt}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10,colframe=black,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
      left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,boxsep=0pt,width=\@tempdima]
    #1
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\vspace{-0.75cm}\mybox{Some text}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\cfoot{}



\nointerlineskip
%%% magic code starts
\mathcode`*=\string"8000
\begingroup
\catcode`*=\active
\xdef*{\noexpand\textup{\string*}}
\endgroup
%%% magic code ends

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$-$}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace*{2.5cm}

\lipsum




\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your `headheight` size is too small -- `fancyhdr` clearly warns you about that. In addition, you're loading some packages twice. `\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm,headheight=90pt]{geometry}` should help, as well as the `nobeforeafter` option to the `tcbset` command. It would also be helpful to have a screen shot was you expect and what bothers you at the moment with the current output

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The main cause of the disrupted display here is a wrong setting of the `\headheight` length.

The `tcolorbox` environment has some skip before and after, without using the `nobeforeafter` option the reported `headheight` should be `90pt`, but can be reduced to `70pt` or slightly below that value.

I did not address other issues in the code, however.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm,,headheight=70pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{longtitle/.style={%
  title={#1},
  nobeforeafter,
  before upper={\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\phantom{#1}\\[\the\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox]},
  after upper={\end{tabular}}}}

\newtcbox{\LongTitleBox}[1][]{longtitle={\Large \textbf{Test Header}},colbacktitle=black,coltitle=white,#1,colback=gray!20,boxrule=1pt}%

\newtcbox{\LongTitleBoxResult}[1][]{enhanced,longtitle={Final Result},colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black, #1}%

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{%
\fancyhead[L]{\LARGE \LongTitleBox{Test Title}}
\fancyhead[R]{Autor Name\\[0.5cm]}%
}



\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\wd0+12pt}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10,colframe=black,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
      left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,boxsep=0pt,width=\@tempdima]
    #1
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\vspace{-0.75cm}\mybox{Some text}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\cfoot{}



\nointerlineskip
%%% magic code starts
\mathcode`*=\string"8000
\begingroup
\catcode`*=\active
\xdef*{\noexpand\textup{\string*}}
\endgroup
%%% magic code ends

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$-$}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace*{2.5cm}

\lipsum




\end{document}
```

[image]